# How openstack-swift synchronize time between different servers?

Tags: openstack, distributed-computing, openstack-swift

Assume, I've two servers which is located in different time-zones. How do swift synchronize objects in different time-zones? How is their implementation? Do they have applied any special algorithm ?

Answer (score 0):

Swift uses UTC so it doesn't bother about timezone.

Answer (score 0):

NTP application should be installed in order to synchronize time globally or between your storage and controller nodes.